# Is my use of the word "award" to describe a blog tagging game correct?

Tags: meaning

Anybody ever run into the blog post tagging? Like when somebody starts posting about certain topic (for example answering certain questions like what are your 10 habits, etc) and then they tag other people to write about the topic too in their own blog. I've never started a game like that but yes, when friends tag me and when I feel like it, I do the homework and pass the tag.

Recently, I realized that the tagging game sometimes has a name. It's called award. I've got the "You're Going Places, Baby!" award from a dear friend of mine. The rules: describe where you think you'll be in 10 years and then pass it along to other bloggers.

Until now, my understanding about the 'award' usage is something given or rewarded because of certain acts (honorable acts). Is 'award' normally used in more generalized definition or is it just in that bloggers game case? For the bloggers case, I think award only means something assigned/given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=award) describes the etymological origin of the verb "award". In a nutshell, it means to   "decide after careful examination and observation". This seems to apply to the blog post tagging award you are talking about.

However, I have not personally seen "award" used in this sense.

Comment: thanks for the link to the etymology dictionary!
I think you're right, that definition does apply.

You could check blogs of 20 something bloggers' members, especially those who have had crowd. They play this blog post tagging every now and then.

Comment: Downvote w/o a comment? I say! Poor form! :)

Answer (score 1):

An award is given as recognition for excellence of some kind.  As long as I can remember, awards have also been given sarcastically or playfully, as a way of teasing or having fun — think of "most likely to..." awards issued in high school yearbooks.  Another example is [The Golden Raspberry Awards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Raspberry_Award) (or Razzies).

So, this is definitely not limited to blogging.

Comment: Hi there! Thanks! 

Even if it's given sarcastically/playfully, awards are still given because of something achieved, while in the blogging game case, the receivers don't do anything. They just receive.

Comment: I would still argue that these awards are in this playful sense, where it is a small step from, say, the high school "most likely to..." award (what do those people achieve?) to this, in terms of the meaning of the word.